# How to Integrate Your Website with Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

Does ANYONE know of a successful integration of Microsoft Dynamics CRM system with a .net website?
I have gone through all the msdn stuff for getting started with the SDK for Microsoft CRM 4.
I am trying to find any other basic examples / blog posts about implementing the SDK for MS CRM4.
Does anyone know of some blogs that cover this?

Comment: msdn is quite complete, and of course depends what are you trying to integrate (for example e-commerce site, service assistant, ...) basically you can do CRUD operation with the CRM data

Comment: what are you trying to "integrate"? Users? Articles? Support calls?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, integrating Dynamics CRM with any .NET application pretty much means fetching/pushing data from/to CRM. In case you're looking for a two way integration, like also including fetching/pushing data from/to your .NET application (from CRM) then you would require CRM plugins/javascripts as well.

Unless you are a complete newbie in Dynamics CRM, you should be able to figure it out pretty easily by going through the SDK here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151016.aspx where all the possible methods have been explained. It's all .NET, so 'integration' is not a very big deal. You just need to keep in mind what kind of authentication you'd be performing in CRM; if that's going to be an impersonation or you'd pass credentials.